# How to create our own Cocoapods if app have already some other pods dependency like Almofire, SwiftJSON, etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, mobile

I have developed my own application and this app have already some pods dependency like Almofire, SwiftJSON, MBProgressHUD and many more. I want to create my own Cocoapods in which these dependency can be linked

Answer (score 7):

Please follow these steps to create your won Cococapods  -

- Create a public repository on your git account

[image: Public Repo]

- Copy Repository Url. Open terminal and run following command.

  git clone <-Repository Url->.git
- Now Copy all the xcode project file and folder inside the cloned
  repo. and run the below command

  git add *

  git commit -m "Initial Setup"

  git push origin master
- Create a new release to go to your git repository or run following
  commands

  git tag 1.0.0

  git push --tags
- Generate create Podspec file

Run the below command to generate the podspec file.

```
touch reponame.podscpec
```

- Open the podspec file on any editor and paste these text as it is.

Format  like below attached screenshot.

[image: Format the string]

Save the file and Now run the below command on terminal.

```
pod lib lint
```

If validation passed. then run the below commands

```
pod trunk register <-abx@xyz.com-> 'user name'
```

You will get an email for verification. Just verify the email and now run the below command.

```
pod trunk push PodName.podspec
```

If all goes well, you will get this on terminal

[image: Sample message]

Congratulations. Now you can use this pod whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this link as well. I have created my own steps with reference for this link to ease the ways.

https://www.appcoda.com/cocoapods-making-guide/